# python code time difference with cut-off time and start time in all columns

Tags: python, time

I want to find diffence of cut-off time and list of end time in pandas columns and append new time in df

```
from datetime import datetime, date

out = datetime.combine(date.today(), datetime.strptime('00:15', '%H:%M').time())
print(out)

# output : datetime.datetime(2020,2,8,0,15)

reception time                     

2022-02-07 18:01:58
2022-02-07 05:05:05
2022-02-07 08:07:34
2022-02-07 09:05:33

find difference of all time and append in new column in df
```

Comment: Is it part of an assignment? Please show your attempts at solving this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your `reception time` is a column of a dataframe, use:

```
df['diff'] = out - pd.to_datetime(df['reception time'])
print(df)

# Output
        reception time            diff
0  2022-02-07 18:01:58 0 days 06:13:02
1  2022-02-07 05:05:05 0 days 19:09:55
2  2022-02-07 08:07:34 0 days 16:07:26
3  2022-02-07 09:05:33 0 days 15:09:27
```

Setup:

```
data = {'reception time': ['2022-02-07 18:01:58', '2022-02-07 05:05:05',
                           '2022-02-07 08:07:34', '2022-02-07 09:05:33']}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(df)

# Output
        reception time
0  2022-02-07 18:01:58
1  2022-02-07 05:05:05
2  2022-02-07 08:07:34
3  2022-02-07 09:05:33
```